# Eliminate folder name from Urls

Tags: wordpress, windows, laravel, .htaccess, xampp

I have WP and Laravel6 with structure.

```
my_site/
    .htaccess
    wp/
    laravel/.htaccess
```

and virtualhost

```
<VirtualHost subdomain.local:777>
    DocumentRoot "c:\xampp\htdocs\my_site"
    ServerName subdomain.local
</VirtualHost>
```

As I want to serve landing page from WP, I do bit changes in root .htaccess to remove **wp** from url

```
RewriteEngine on
# remove wp from urls
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.local:777$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.local:777$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp/index.php [L]
```

now subdomain.local:777 shows wp landing page.

Next I want to eliminate laravel folder from urls which are serving from laravel ie:

```
subdomain.local:777/laravel/login to subdomain.local:777/login
subdomain.local:777/laravel/profile to subdomain.local:777/profile
```

and so on..

for that I add following into **laravel/.htaccess** but it crash all routes..

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^laravel/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

with error

```
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
subdomain.local
Apache/2.4.37 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1 PHP/7.2.12
```

additionally my **laravel/.htaccess** file also configuring css/js/image/fonts to work like so

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt|\.woff|\.woff2|\.ttf)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images|google_map|image_compressor|admin-files|fontawesome-free|webfonts)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

or do I need to edit in **c:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf**

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved by bit changes in root .htaccess. such that the final version of .htaccess is now

```
RewriteEngine on
# remove wp from urls
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.local:777$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.local:777$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp/index.php [L]

# Rewrite Laravel Routes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/profile
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]
```